# Trying to execute a method once, on a JButton

Tags: java, swing, action, listener, jbutton

I'm currently working on a java project to keep me busy for the summer. I've just finished my first year of University so I have a basic knowledge of Java and how it works. For my project I've decided to make a choose you own adventure game sort of thing. Where the user is given some dialogue then they are given two options of how to proceed. So far it's going well and I've came to a flaw that I can't get my head around solving. Below is my code for my primary class.

---

```
public DisplayPanel() {
        core = new Core();
        stat = new StatusPanel();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Quest!");

        middle = new JPanel();
        bottom = new JPanel();
        left = new JButton("Explore");
        right = new JButton("Think");
        textArea = new JTextArea();

        middle.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        middle.add(textArea);
        bottom.add(stat);


        left.addActionListener(this);
        right.addActionListener(this);


        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(left, BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(right, BorderLayout.EAST);
        add(middle, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(bottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        changeText("You wake up in a strange woods and walk forwards into the mist\n " +
                "You decide whether it's best to think how you got here " +
                "\n or search the area for clues");



        setSize(600, 700);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void changeText(String newText) {
        textArea.setText(newText);
    }

    public static void appendText(String newText) {
        textArea.append(newText);
    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        String cmd = e.getActionCommand();
        Monsters m = new Monsters();


        try {
            core.load("goblinstier1.txt");
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }


        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        /////////////////////////////LEFT/////OPTION1////////////////////////////
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //////////////////////////////ORIGINAL CHOICE////////////////////////////
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        if(e.getSource() == left) {
            textArea.setText("You explore the area for clues and hear a rustling in a bush.\n " +
                    "It might be someone who can help? Or it could be a monster! \n" +
                    "You ready your knife in preperation!\n");
            stat.incrementClickCount();

            option2a = new JButton("Talk");
            option2a.addActionListener(this);
            option2a.setActionCommand("left2a"); 
            add(option2a, BorderLayout.WEST);

            option2b = new JButton("Leave");
            option2b.addActionListener(this);
            option2b.setActionCommand("right2b"); 
            add(option2b, BorderLayout.EAST);

            right.setVisible(false);
            left.setVisible(false);


        }


        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ////////////////////////////LEFTA/////OPTION2////////////////////////////
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        Monsters temp = null;
        temp = core.anyMonster();




        if(cmd == "left2a") {
            option2a.setText("Attack!");
            option2b.setText("Flee!");
            stat.incrementClickCount();
            fightClick++;



                if(fightClick >=2) {

                    appendText("You grip your shiv and cleave!");
                    temp.cleave();

                    if(temp.getHealth()<=0) {
                        appendText("You have " +stat.getHealth2()+ " health remaining ");
                        stat.gold();
                        stat.xp();

                    }else {
                        stat.hit();
                    }
                }

        }
```

My problem lies within LEFTA Option two I've tried to script a sort of fight system where the user has the chance to fight or flee. The way this works is by a method in my core class called anyMonster I will display it below.

```
public Monsters anyMonster() {
        int index = randomGenerator.nextInt(monsters.size());
        Monsters monsters1 = monsters.get(index);
        DisplayPanel.changeText("A monster appears! It's a " + monsters1 + "!\n What shall you do?\n");
        return monsters1;
    }
```

The method loops through a pre set arrayList and picks a "Monster" at random. As you can see in the DisplayPanel I tried to call this in the actionPerformed class and then if the user presses a button it will attack the monster, code below.

```
public void cleave()
    {
        randomNum = 7 + (int)(Math.random() * ((10 - 7) + 1));

        newHealth=health-randomNum;
        health=newHealth;
        DisplayPanel.appendText(" You attack for " +randomNum+ " Damage, it has " +health+ " health remaining!\n ");
        if(health<=0){
            DisplayPanel.appendText("The monster falls to the ground");
        }
}
}
```

The way i made this work in DisplayPanel was assigning the method to a temp value and then calling the cleave() method from that which works. The problem is that every time i click the button it will select a new monster each time. I realise why this is happening, of course it's a button it will just do the same action each time. The problem is I'm completely out of ideas on how to solve this. Which is frustrating, I'd really like to continue with my project and any help you can give to a newbie would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance, Rob.

Comment: Put the chosen monster into some variable?

Comment: I see an even bigger issue in that you are mixing data with code, hard-coding your explorer's location and state in your program's code. I think that you'll not want to do this, else you'll be forced to hard-code everything making for a huge, inflexible impossible to debug or modify God class.

Comment: Yu some kind of centralised model that make deacons based on the current state of the game. So if some monster exists, you would execute the combat branch, otherwise you would execute the adventure branch or what else you need to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than create your minsters in actionPerformed, you should create this as a field, that way your monsters are only created once.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure I understand what you mean, my Java lingo is a bit useless. As in create it as an instance variable? And by monsters do you mean the monsters class, or the anyMonster method? Could you perhaps provide me with a short example? Many thanks.